# FileNotFoundException while watching variables in debug mode

Tags: c#, .net, exception, filenotfoundexception

I have this piece of code (well I have the issue everywhere)

When I debug this, break in the funcion, try to watch some variables. And I keep getting a `FileNotFoundException`

```
    public void PayrollActivityCodeTest()
    {
        using(var pr = new ActivityCodeProcess())
        {
            pr.Add();
            pr.WorkingEntity.PayrollConfiguration.Provinces = PayrollProvincesType.QC | PayrollProvincesType.ON;

            pr.WorkingEntity.ActivityCodeId = "01";
            //pr.WorkingEntity.Rates.CodeByProvinceCollection.First().CodeValueCollection.FirstOrDefault().Value
            Assert.AreEqual(2, pr.WorkingEntity.Rates.CodeByProvinceCollection.Count);
        }
    }
```

[image]

But the "missing" DLL is in the folder, it's not readonly or any other flags Windows has.

[image]

Comment: What is logged if you enable logging in [fuslogvw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx)? I expect another dependency to fail.

Comment: might something to do with the dll version

Comment: Is P: a network drive, by any chance, and are you running VS/the debugger elevated? Mapped drives aren't visible under elevated credentials. A possible workaround is to use the full UNC path instead.

Comment: and what process monitor says? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: @rene it displays nothing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Nop it's not network, and yes VS is in Admin mode.

Comment: @MiłoszWierzbicki looking at the process monitor. What am I supposed to look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Use managed compatibility mode` has to be activated 
[image]

Comment: I'm working on a c# Excel plugin with ExcelDna and this actually made previously `FileNotFoundException` fields appear correctly in the debugger. Thank you!